# How to add keys from a HashMap into a list with the same order in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, hashmap

I've used a HashMap to order keys out from their values. Now I want the keys transfered over to a list, where the order of the keys will be the same. I've tried multiple option to add each key to a list, but none of them keeps the same order of the keys, as they had in the HashMap.

Comment: Use a LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 2):

[`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is the most known and common implementation of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). However:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

If you want to persist the order in which the elements have been put to the `Map`, you need to use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) implementation. As the documentation states:

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).